# pandas rolling over irregular dataset with irregular window size

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate a median over an irregular pandas series.

In particular, I want to calculate the median first based on the first X-days and later based on the following X-days.

I did code the following working example. In there, I generate two columns, one `median_-2days` which lists the median based on the previous two days and one `median_+2days` which does the same based on the next 2 days.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def dummy_data():
    idx = np.array([pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=1),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=2),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=3),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=5),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=6),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=8),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=9),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=10),
                    ])
    data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10])
    return pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=["l"])


def rolling_median_irregular(ds, left, right):
    res = pd.Series(index=ds.index)
    for t in ds.index:
        val = ds.loc[(ds.index >= t - left) & (ds.index <= t + right)].median()
        res.loc[t] = val
    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = dummy_data()
    df["median_-2days"] = rolling_median_irregular(df["l"], left=pd.Timedelta(days=2), right=pd.Timedelta(days=0))
    df["median_+2days"] = rolling_median_irregular(df["l"], left=pd.Timedelta(days=0), right=pd.Timedelta(days=2))
```

However, I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel. I would prefer to use the built-in `rolling` function to have a more general approach where I can also use different functions (like `.sum()` or `.mean()`) and different window types.

Is it even possible to do this with the built-in functions or do I have to subclass a `BaseIndexer`? If this is the case, how would this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rolling` with a window of 3D as you want to include the boundary with `>=` and `<=`. to do the left and right, you can reverse the series with `[::-1]` so it is done with:

```
df["median_-2days_r"] = df.loc[:,'l'].rolling('3D').median()
df["median_+2days_r"] = df.loc[::-1, 'l'].rolling('3D').median()
print(df)
             l  median_-2days  median_+2days  median_-2days_r  median_+2days_r
2021-01-01   1            1.0            2.0              1.0              2.0
2021-01-02   2            1.5            2.5              1.5              2.5
2021-01-03   3            2.0            4.0              2.0              4.0
2021-01-05   5            4.0            5.5              4.0              5.5
2021-01-06   6            5.5            7.0              5.5              7.0
2021-01-08   8            7.0            9.0              7.0              9.0
2021-01-09   9            8.5            9.5              8.5              9.5
2021-01-10  10            9.0           10.0              9.0             10.0
```

**Edit**: with the specification given about duplicates index and the size of data, you can try per dataframe

```
#sample data
np.random.seed(10)
df_ = pd.DataFrame(
        index=np.tile(np.random.choice(
                         pd.date_range('2021-03-03','2021-03-04',freq='T'),
                         size=1000, replace=False), 
                      5), 
        data={'l':range(5000)}
        ).sort_index()
#your method for reference
df_['median_func'] = rolling_median_irregular(df_["l"], left=pd.Timedelta(minutes=15), 
                                              right=pd.Timedelta(minutes=0))
#using concat
df_['median_concat'] = (
    pd.concat([df_[['l']].set_index(df_.index+pd.Timedelta(minutes=i)) 
                                              #here put -i for other direction
               for i in range(0,16)])
      .groupby(level=0)
      .median()
    )
```

So you get

```
print(df_.head(12))
                        l  median_concat  median_func
2021-03-03 00:01:00  3357         2357.0       2357.0
2021-03-03 00:01:00   357         2357.0       2357.0
2021-03-03 00:01:00  4357         2357.0       2357.0
2021-03-03 00:01:00  1357         2357.0       2357.0
2021-03-03 00:01:00  2357         2357.0       2357.0
2021-03-03 00:03:00  3903         2630.0       2630.0
2021-03-03 00:03:00   903         2630.0       2630.0
2021-03-03 00:03:00  2903         2630.0       2630.0
2021-03-03 00:03:00  1903         2630.0       2630.0
2021-03-03 00:03:00  4903         2630.0       2630.0
2021-03-03 00:06:00  2505         2505.0       2505.0
2021-03-03 00:06:00  3505         2505.0       2505.0
```

and for a timing, I get about 80x faster

```
%timeit rolling_median_irregular(df_["l"], left=pd.Timedelta(minutes=15), right=pd.Timedelta(minutes=0))
# 2.12 s ± 74.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit pd.concat([df_[['l']].set_index(df_.index+pd.Timedelta(minutes=i)) for i in range(0,16)]).groupby(level=0).median()
#25.1 ms ± 1.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: that looks promising. So it seems like the trick is to reverse the series to get the median of the following two days.

Comment: @user7431005 yes it is the trick and thanks to index alignment, no need to reverse the series after to get the right date. except if you have duplicates dates in the index

Comment: unfortunately, this is the case, I have duplicated dates in there. The reversing is not the problem but the pandas rolling is not considering duplicated dates correctly. In my example, If I change the 2nd index to `2021-01-01` (same as first), the first rolling median is incorrect - I'll have to think about a solution to this...

Comment: @user7431005 how big is the data, how many differnet days and are you going to do windows bigger than couple of days?

Comment: My real data is the following: A pandas DataFrame covers 1 day, Within this day, I can have up to 5000 samples (observations) at 1000 distinct times. I want to group it by 15min. (thus, I have 1000 distinct indices and 5000 rows). 
In total, I have some thousand of these data frames (that are completely independent).

Comment: @user7431005 see the edit, it is the fastest I could think of with your data requirements

Comment: Thanks for the additional tests. I'll implement it using your suggestion

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it still does not work properly since my data is really irregular. Thus, it might be that two observations are only 1 millisecond apart and not only a multiple of 1 minute. Your algorithm assumes that the difference is always a multiple of one minute. If you change your `freq='T'` to `freq='s'` and compare our approaches you will see what I mean. I'll ask a more detailed question with the additional constraints tomorrow since this is becoming off-topic.Never the less, your help with inversing the series is worth an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are reinventing the wheel.

You only need to specify the `window= '2D'` argument in `pd.rolling` to be able to roll over fixed time periods, like two days (as opposted to a fixed number of observations)

Comment: I tried this, but how can I now say that it should use the previous two days only or the following two days only? (`left`/`right` in my code?)

Comment: nope, the result is still different. `df["l"].rolling("-2D").median()` returns `2.0` for the 2nd day. The correct value would be `1.5` for my `"median_-2days"` case

Comment: you can tweak where the window is closed (left, right), and other parameters to match what you have in mind. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html